# How to fetch month from server in php?

Tags: php

I am using date('F') function for fetching the current month but this one automatically changes if i change my system's date. Is there any method to fetch it from server?

Comment: It does get it from the server...

Comment: if your code is running on localhost, then it will happen (because your system is iteself a server for your code). put your code on some real server, and it will work perfectly fine. (i am hoping that you are runing your code on localhost)

Comment: Are you running on a localhost running on your PC, if so then the server is also the client, and this would be expected

Comment: php cannot read the client time, cause it is a serverside language. As long as you are running browser and server on the same machine you can modify the date by changing your "client" system time

Comment: `$time = file_get_contents ('http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now');`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language, if it is run on a server it will return the server time. If you run it on a local system then and you change your local time it will take that local time because your local system is your server. If you always want the right time use a server that is connected to an NTP server of your country.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running at localhost server. Place your code to any real server. After that it will work. :)